# Saving a product

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I've seen in some code posted the use  `$product->getResource()->save($product)` or `$product->save()` to save changes to a product.

What's the difference between them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Later is just a wrapper.

Magento uses a resource to do database operation. so when you perform `$product->save()`, it will call `$product->getResource()->save($product)` to perform save action.

But my recommendation is use `save()` action whenever it is possible because it provide lot of other useful terminologies. See `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::save()` method

```
public function save()
{
    /**
     * Direct deleted items to delete method
     */
    if ($this->isDeleted()) {
        return $this->delete();
    }
    if (!$this->_hasModelChanged()) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->_getResource()->beginTransaction();
    $dataCommited = false;
    try {
        $this->_beforeSave();
        if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
            $this->_getResource()->save($this);
            $this->_afterSave();
        }
        $this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
            ->commit();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = false;
        $dataCommited = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_getResource()->rollBack();
        $this->_hasDataChanges = true;
        throw $e;
    }
    if ($dataCommited) {
        $this->_afterSaveCommit();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You can see here `$this->_getResource()->save($this);` This is exactly same as calling resource and perform save.

Other than this, there are lot of other advnatages. It includes :

1. Fire before, after model save events.
2. Delete entity if necessary
3. Skip save action if no data changes
4. Proper error handling and so on.

But in some scenarios, it may be a burden to do all these things. It would be better to perform only "save" action rather than all other supporting features which I described above. In those cases, you can use resource save directly.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: But strangely when i try to `$product->setCategoryIds($categories);` , the changes are saved only when i use the call to the resource not the wrapper ?

Comment: @magentonewbie I am not sure why it is not working in your context, but you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6512286 where save action actually work in order to save category Ids

Comment: @magentonewbie see my updated answer. it will give more idea.